# Re-writing Query

Tags: oracle, plsql, extract, cursors

Overall Task :- I need to retrieve data from 45 fields in system A and dump that data into a temp table which is then picked up by a unix process which produces an xml data file to be imported into system B.

Specific Question : What would be the best way of retrieving the data to be written into the 45 fields.  Majority of the data is independent and can't be retrieved using a single statement. The way i currently retrieve this data is as follows (example below)

My temp tables hold the affected properties ID that i need to extract data for. i.e PROP_LIST_TEMP and ASSOC_PROP_TEMP.

```
    SELECT SUBSTR (pro.pro_propref, 1, 25)                                  UPRN,
(SELECT SUBSTR (adr_building, 1, 100)
               FROM addresses, address_usages
              WHERE     aus_adr_refno = adr_refno
                    AND aus_aut_far_code = 'PHYSICAL'
                    AND aus_aut_fao_code = 'PRO'
                    AND (aus_end_date IS NULL OR aus_end_date > SYSDATE)
                    AND aus_pro_refno = pro.pro_refno)
                                                                                 BUILDING_NAME,          
               (SELECT CASE
                        WHEN (adr_street_number like 'BLOC%' 
                              OR adr_street_number like '%-%'
                              OR adr_street_number like '%/%')
                        THEN NULL
                        ELSE regexp_replace (adr_street_number, '[^[:digit:]]+')
                        END
                  FROM addresses, address_usages
                  WHERE aus_adr_refno = adr_refno
                    AND aus_aut_far_code = 'PHYSICAL'
                    AND aus_aut_fao_code = 'PRO'
                    AND (aus_end_date IS NULL OR aus_end_date > SYSDATE)
                    AND aus_pro_refno = pro.pro_refno)
                                                                               STREET_NUMBER,
               (SELECT CASE 
                        WHEN (adr_street_number like 'BLOC%' 
                              OR adr_street_number like '%-%'
                              OR adr_street_number like '%/%')
                        THEN SUBSTR (adr_street_number, 1, 20)
                        ELSE  REGEXP_REPLACE (adr_street_number, '[^[:alpha:]]+', '')
                        END
                  FROM addresses, address_usages
                  WHERE aus_adr_refno = adr_refno
                    AND aus_aut_far_code = 'PHYSICAL'
                    AND aus_aut_fao_code = 'PRO'
                    AND (aus_end_date IS NULL OR aus_end_date > SYSDATE)
                    AND aus_pro_refno = pro.pro_refno)
                                                                                STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX,
               (SELECT SUBSTR (ptv_pty_code, 1, 3)
                  FROM prop_type_values
                 WHERE ptv_refno = pro.pro_hou_ptv_refno)
                                                                               HOUSE_TYPE
FROM properties pro
         WHERE pro_refno IN (select * from PIMSS_PROP_LIST_TEMP  
                             UNION
                             select * from PIMSS_ASSOC_PROP_TEMP)
         AND  pro.pro_hou_hrv_hot_code IN 
                                       (SELECT frv_code
                                          FROM first_ref_values
                                         WHERE frv_frd_domain IN ('ASS_OWN_REF')
                                           AND frv_current_ind = 'Y');
```

Comment: Seems pretty good to me. If it's all independent data, there isn't really much you can do to optimize it.

Comment: Anyway of combining the data retrieved for building_name and street_number as they hit the same rows/tables...in my example that would be a fresh call to database for every field.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. Well, you could alias that table with all those `where`s and `and`s in a `with` clause, and all the data you retreive from it could be in subqueries. Not sure if it would go any faster, but it might look better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the where clauses of the subqueries in the select statement are identical, you could simply pull that out into the where clause, like so:

```
SELECT SUBSTR (pro.pro_propref, 1, 25) UPRN,
       SUBSTR (addr.adr_building, 1, 100) BUILDING_NAME,          
       CASE WHEN (addr.adr_street_number like 'BLOC%' 
                  OR addr.adr_street_number like '%-%'
                  OR addr.adr_street_number like '%/%')
                 THEN NULL
            ELSE regexp_replace (addr.adr_street_number, '[^[:digit:]]+')
       END STREET_NUMBER,
       CASE WHEN (addr.adr_street_number like 'BLOC%' 
                  OR addr.adr_street_number like '%-%'
                  OR addr.adr_street_number like '%/%')
                 THEN SUBSTR (addr.adr_street_number, 1, 20)
            ELSE  REGEXP_REPLACE (addr.adr_street_number, '[^[:alpha:]]+', '')
       END STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX,
       (SELECT SUBSTR (ptv_pty_code, 1, 3)
          FROM prop_type_values
         WHERE ptv_refno = pro.pro_hou_ptv_refno) HOUSE_TYPE
FROM   properties pro,
       (select adr_building,
               adr_street_number
        FROM   addresses, address_usages
        WHERE  aus_adr_refno = adr_refno
        AND    aus_aut_far_code = 'PHYSICAL'
        AND    aus_aut_fao_code = 'PRO'
        AND    (aus_end_date IS NULL OR aus_end_date > SYSDATE)) addr
WHERE  pro.pro_refno = aus_pro_refno
and    pro_refno IN (select * from PIMSS_PROP_LIST_TEMP  
                     UNION
                     select * from PIMSS_ASSOC_PROP_TEMP)
AND    pro.pro_hou_hrv_hot_code IN (SELECT frv_code
                                      FROM first_ref_values
                                     WHERE frv_frd_domain IN ('ASS_OWN_REF')
                                       AND frv_current_ind = 'Y');
```

You might possibly need an outer join if there's a chance that no rows could be returned from the addr subquery.

Comment: Would this have any speed advantage over my version or just the same?

Comment: I would imagine that my query would be faster, since you're no longer querying the same table 3 times. However, it's possible that any sub-query caching taking place in your original query might be more beneficial. It's up to you to test both queries and decide which works for you, with the data that you have.